# make django not insert certain fields

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin, django-1.9

I have a Django model against a postgresql database table where I want Django to not insert field_3 during object creation as its a timestamp field that DB is supposed to fill in.

```
class AbcModel:
  model_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  field_1 = models.BigIntegerField()
  field_2 = models.TextField()
  field_3 = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

  class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'abc_table'
```

The corresponding table schema

abc_table

- model_id integer not null default
  nextval('command_running_command_id_seq'::regclass)
- field_1 integer not null
- field_2 text not null
- field_3 timestamp without time zone default now()

What I tried -
I read that one should call Model.save(update_fields=[list of fields to be updated]).

```
class AbcModel(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        u_fields = ['field_1', 'field_2']
        super(CommandRunning, self).save(update_fields=u_fields)
```

But I get an Exception

```
Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key.
```

If I include model_id in update_fields, I get following exception

```
The following fields do not exist in this model or are m2m fields: model_id
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you need the database to add the timestamp? You can just set ```field_3 = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)```to add the date and not have to worry about finding a workaround? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't own the database schema. I am supposed to provide only an admin interface over it. Django looked like a natural choice with its amazing inspectdb command but the model file it generates requires a bit of modification to truly align to database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fact: whenever one specifies update_fields, it forces save to update. This doesn't help during insert as we don't have auto-generated primary key available.

Final Solution:

there is a method called _do_insert which gets called just before the insert query is fired to the database. One can override it and remove fields which we don't want to insert

```
def _do_insert(self, manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw):
        return super(AbcModel, self)._do_insert(
            manager, using,
            [f for f in fields if f.attname not in ['field_3']],
            update_pk, raw)
```

For better understanding, try to look into the insert query generated. You will see that field_3 is missing in the insert SQL sent to the database. This allows database to insert the field using the specified default.

Comment: how about returning the `field_3` value generated by db?

Comment: I might also need to override `_do_update` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71916937/9035706