# Django tries to write to a generated column

Tags: django, postgresql

I've added GIN index to my db

```
ALTER TABLE mtn_order
ADD COLUMN textsearchable_index_col tsvector
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_tsvector('english', coalesce(descr, '') || ' ' || coalesce(descrrep, ''))) STORED;
CREATE INDEX textsearch_idx ON mtn_order USING GIN (textsearchable_index_col);
```

and `textsearchable_index_col = SearchVectorField(null=True)` to my model and now when i'm trying to save new instance i get:

```
ProgrammingError at /order/create/
cannot insert into column "textsearchable_index_col"
DETAIL:  Column "textsearchable_index_col" is a generated column.
```

How to stop Django trying to write `None` to that field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't be able to add it as a field to your model, because Django will try to write values back to it.

You could annotate it on when you need to:

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(
    index_col=RawSQL('textsearchable_index_col', 
                     [], 
                     output_field=SearchVectorField()
)
```

Comment: For those of you wishing to track generated columns without having to resort to rawsql calls, follow this django project ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30511

Comment: That ticket looks like it’s limited to generated as identity columns?

Comment: I'd also thought that, but the django community closes tickets and marks them as duplicates for any `GENERATED AS` functionality and points back to the ticket I previously linked. Examples: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31565 and https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31300

Comment: I think the suggestion is that the infrastructure and functionality for any GENERATED AS columns would be resolved by #30511.

Answer (score 0):

Override the _do_insert and _do_update methods on the model:

```
class MTNOrder:

    def _do_insert(self, manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw):
        fields = [
            f for f in fields if f.attname not in ['textsearchable_index_col']
        ]
        return super()._do_insert(manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

    def _do_update(self, base_qs, using, pk_val, values, update_fields, forced_update):
        values = [
            value for value in values if value[0].attname not in ['textsearchable_index_col']
        ]
        return super()._do_update(base_qs, using, pk_val, values, update_fields, forced_update)
```

Reference: [make django not insert certain fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551476/make-django-not-insert-certain-fields)